# Why are there junk "files" in my Fat32 SD rood dir

Tags: sd-card, fat32

I have been building a program to access files on a Fat32 micro sd card. However, when I run my program or open my SD card with a hex viewer to the root directory I can see my [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JETAv.png) but there are also a bunch of junk mixed in, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Directory data is organized in 32 byte records. This is nice, because any sector holds
exactly 16 records, and no directory record will ever cross a sector boundry. There
are four types of 32-byte directory records.

1. Normal record with short filename - Attrib is normal
2. Long filename text - Attrib has all four type bits set
3. Unused - First byte is 0xE5
4. End of directory - First byte is zero

Unused directory records are a result of deleting files. The first byte is overwritten
with 0xE5, and later when a new file is created it can be reused. At the end of the directory is a record that begins with zero. All other records will be non-zero in their
first byte, so this is an easy way to determine when you have reached the end of the
directory.
Records that do not begin with 0xE5 or zero are actual directory data, and the format
can be determined by checking the Attrib byte. For now, we are only going to be
concerned with the normal directory records that have the old 8.3 short filename
format. In FAT32, all files and subdirectories have short names, even if the user gave
the file a longer name, so you can access all files without needing to decode the long
filename records (as long as your code simply ignores them).